# error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-041300-generic' not found , how to create?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

After upgrading to 17.10, the following error appears:

```
error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-041300-generic' not found   
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

Through another installed OS, I can take a look at the /boot/ directory, showing the following content:

[image]

Where I can clearly see that the "missing" file is actually there.

So how can I solve this problem?