# Revert changes made to efibootmgr

Tags: boot, grub2, efibootmgr

Before trying to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 all over again, erasing previous OS (Ubuntu 18.04), I did some modifications to efibootmgr.

Installation was made on the SSD (NVMe drive), and not in the Harddrive, which is giving me all kinds of trouble. All in UEFI.

The new install cannot boot because the boot files are "missing". The changes I made to efibootmgr before are still there even after complete erasing of the previous disks and complete reinstall. What I changed was adding entries grub-NVMe and boot-NVMe (see [How to set mount point of boot partition to /boot/efi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043531/how-to-set-mount-point-of-boot-partition-to-boot-efi/1043595#1043595)). These entries are still there along with new ones, and overall all looks pretty messy.

Now the entries of efibootmgr -v are the following

efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 100C
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0009,0008,0006,000A,000B,0001,0002,0004,0005
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c58d6abb-383b-4281-   bb6d-4296ca698224,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* grub  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0002* boot  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0004* grub-NVMe VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0005* boot-NVMe VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0006* Diskette Drive          BBS(Floppy,,0x0)..GO..NO[.......+.D.i.s.k.e.t.t.e.  .D.r.i.v.e.........................rN.D+..,.\...........BO
Boot0007* M.2 PCIe SSD  BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........u.M...2. .P.C.I.e. .S.S.D....................A.............................q.........8..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.E.I.7.7.M.0.0.0.1.1.0.8.0.7.K.0.K........BO
Boot0008* Hard Drive    BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.H.a.r.d. .D.r.i.v.e....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .4.Z.8.Z.L.X.9.1........BO
Boot0009* USB Storage Device    BBS(PCMCIA,,0x0)..GO..NO........m.U.S.B. .S.t.o.r.a.g.e. .D.e.v.i.c.e....................A.......................@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.7.2.7.0.9.4.6.7.7.5.9.1.5.2.6.2.9.2.4.2........BO
Boot000A* CD/DVD/CD-RW Device   BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.C.D./.D.V.D./.C.D.-.R.W. .D.e.v.i.c.e....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Z.K.H.3.1.8.2.8.0.4. .4. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot000B* NetWork   BBS(Network,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.N.e.t.W.o.r.k.........................rN.D+..,.\...........@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Q.u.a.l.c.o.m.m. .A.t.h.e.r.o.s. .B.o.o.t........BO
```

Could this setting might be the reason why Ubuntu can't boot? How can I reset efibootmgr to a "normal" looking one, if necessary?

blkid:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="ABAB-B1AB" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="c58d6abb-383b-4281-bb6d-4296ca698224"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="da07a979-a548-4e38-9133-e543bc486a07" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="8cf26198-05be-4f47-aad7-44045c44b460"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="UBUNTU 16_0" UUID="B6D7-AAC4" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Microsoft Basic Data" PARTUUID="cb704399-f613-41df-9175-a42e3d645032"
```

I can only run Ubuntu Live from a USB, as the installation of Ubuntu does no boot. I am trying to set the correct entries for the whole procedure to work, because no matter how I install Ubuntu, fstab, grub and efibootmgr have weird entries which do not reset.

**The goal is being able to install ubuntu on the SSD (nvme0n1p1) on an UEFI system, no dual boot, no data to lose, and make it work, avoiding the error "no boot device found"**

efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 100C
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0009,0008,0006,000A,000B,0001,0002,0004,0005
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c58d6abb-383b-4281-bb6d-4296ca698224,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* grub  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0002* boot  VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0004* grub-NVMe VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0005* boot-NVMe VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0006* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,,0x0)..GO..NO[.......+.D.i.s.k.e.t.t.e. .D.r.i.v.e.........................rN.D+..,.\...........BO
Boot0007* M.2 PCIe SSD  BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........u.M...2. .P.C.I.e. .S.S.D....................A.............................q.........8..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.E.I.7.7.M.0.0.0.1.1.0.8.0.7.K.0.K........BO
Boot0008* Hard Drive    BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.H.a.r.d. .D.r.i.v.e....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . . . . . . . .4.Z.8.Z.L.X.9.1........BO
Boot0009* USB Storage Device    BBS(PCMCIA,,0x0)..GO..NO........m.U.S.B. .S.t.o.r.a.g.e. .D.e.v.i.c.e....................A.......................@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.7.2.7.0.9.4.6.7.7.5.9.1.5.2.6.2.9.2.4.2........BO
Boot000A* CD/DVD/CD-RW Device   BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.C.D./.D.V.D./.C.D.-.R.W. .D.e.v.i.c.e....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Z.K.H.3.1.8.2.8.0.4. .4. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot000B* NetWork   BBS(Network,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.N.e.t.W.o.r.k.........................rN.D+..,.\...........@..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Q.u.a.l.c.o.m.m. .A.t.h.e.r.o.s. .B.o.o.t........BO
```

Notice how there are a lot of entries on efibootmgr, and most of them point to no existing partition (99e27e... not in my blkid list, not to mention Boot0007 to 000B).

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=da07a979-a548-4e38-9133-e543bc486a07 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=ABAB-B1AB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=1aa6ab58-4338-4c34-941d-6a9ee82046dc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop0         7:0    0   1.5G  1 loop /rofs
sdc           8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1        8:33   1   7.5G  0 part /cdrom
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  15.9G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 460.5G  0 part
```

**/boot/efi is empty**, so on efibootmgr, trying to boot from Boot0000 ubuntu /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi surely wont work, as there is no such file nor folder. Dont understand why this is empty.

sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1p1 print

```
Model: NVMe Device (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1p1: 537MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  537MB  537MB  fat32
```

I feel the main issues are the empty /efi/ folder without shimx64.efi file, and the weird other entries on efibootmgr.

Any help on how to achieve stable settings?

Comment: See `man efibootmgr` and -b option. Like: `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` where XXXX is number of entry. Only delete those that do not work and check order after any change. Probably 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 & 0005. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743

Comment: Hi @oldfred, yeah I learned how to add and remove entries to efibootmgr from you help in my other post. My question is as to what should be done here. Nothing works, so I could really remove everything, but should I replace it with entries directing to my NVMe drive?

Comment: This is a bit of a longshot, but is it possible that going into the Boot Options of the UEFI(BIOS) and looking at the OS boot Manager will show what options the UEFI is trying to boot from? I'm just wondering whether the UEFI is trying to boot from another (incorrect, damaged or non-existent) option first, before the 'proper' entry, then experiencing errors and not trying the other boot options? It shouldn't be doing that but it might be worth checking to rule it out.

Comment: @pHeLiOn I think you might be right. I was actually able to -at least momentarly- solve the problem, by... just deleting the entries that did not make sense (Boot0001 to 0005) from efibootmgr, like oldfred suggested. This somehow resolved the issue. I did not understand how this could be, but your suggestion might explain this, as it might have been booting from other places first... not sure still what happened, and whether it has a better fix

Comment: Are you sure /EFI/ubuntu is empty? If mounted in fstab, it will have umask=0077which is no permissions at all. You then can only see it from live installer. Boot-Repair does automatically change to defaults which Ubuntu used back with 14.04. I think they changed to restrict access for security reasons. I change mine to defaults as I want to often make changes in my ESP, but may change to the 0077 and have to use live installer to update or edit ESP.

Comment: @oldfred after deleting the NVMe entries on efibootmgr and rebooting the computer, ubuntu on the SSD booted correctly, and now boot/efi/ is visible

Comment: @hirschme `/boot/efi` is typically an empty folder and used as mount-point for the ESP. You see the files in `/boot/efi` now because the ESP is mounted. If you look from Live-USB at the folder on the disk, nothing is mounted to it at this time and it appears empty.